# Why does window.indexedDB evaluate to undefined? (How to use IndexedDB?)

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

I am messing around with HTML5's IndexedDB.

Below is a simple code from http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/index.html#slide31  that is not working for me in Chrome or Firefox, it is giving me this message in Firebug:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'open' of undefined`

for the 1st line of the code, which is:

```
var db = window.indexedDB.open('FriendDB', 'My Friends!');  // exception here
```

Can someone help me to get this working please?

[There is a JSFiddle running the code](http://jsfiddle.net/TU7mp/2/)

---

I know this works on the browser because this interactive slide works: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/index.html#slide34

Comment: `window.indexedDB` is undefined then. Find the browser/environment that demo is for (a *recent* Webkit? Safari?). Don't expect it to work elsewhere :)

Comment: @pst I have added a JSFiddle page above.  I am running `Firefox 8.0.1` and `Chrome 15.0.874.121 m`  the `IndexedDB` works in both these browsers just fine, just not the code above for me

Comment: I wonder if it has to be enabled somehow. I can't get *either* openDatabase or indexedDB to work, as per http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/06/comparing-indexeddb-and-webdatabase/

Comment: @pst I don't think so.  On this page here http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/index.html#slide34 there is a demo you can add and remove items from the DB and it is working in both my browsers

Comment: Definitely something else to do with the page. Open up the FF Web-Console on SO: `window.indexedDB` evaluates to `undefined`. Open up the FF Web-Console on the linked slide: `window.indexedDB` evaluates to `[object IDBFactory]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the prefixed version for each browser (`window.webkitIndexedDB` or `window.mozIndexedDB`). Then you can do something like:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB
                     || window.webkitIndexedDB
                     || window.mozIndexedDB;
```

and then use `window.indexedDB` everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

As far as vendor prefixed extensions in Chrome, if you want to use the full IndexedDB API there's more to it than just `window.indexedDB`. I'm working on an [MIT licensed IndexedDB wrapper](http://github.com/editor/InDB). Here's a simplified version of its `fixBrowser()` method in case it might be of help. It should standardized the interface across Chrome and FF.

```
InDB.fixBrowser = function () {
    if ( 'webkitIndexedDB' in window ) {
        window.IDBCursor = window.webkitIDBCursor;
        window.IDBDatabase = window.webkitIDBDatabase;
        window.IDBDatabaseError = window.webkitIDBDatabaseError;
        window.IDBDatabaseException = window.webkitIDBDatabaseException;
        window.IDBErrorEvent = window.webkitIDBErrorEvent;
        window.IDBEvent = window.webkitIDBEvent;
        window.IDBFactory = window.webkitIDBFactory;
        window.IDBIndex = window.webkitIDBIndex;
        window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
        window.IDBObjectStore = window.webkitIDBObjectStore;
        window.IDBRequest = window.webkitIDBRequest;
        window.IDBSuccessEvent = window.webkitIDBSuccessEvent;
        window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
        window.indexedDB = window.webkitIndexedDB;
    } else if ( 'mozIndexedDB' in window ) {
        window.indexedDB = window.mozIndexedDB;
    }
}
```

Comment: My goodness. They couldn't have used `window.webkit|moz|foo.whatever`? :(

Comment: thanks for the post, I looked at your project.  I wish they would of stuck with the WebSQL instead of IndexedDB it seems so much more complex

Comment: Doesn't modernizr do this for you? Or does it only handle the indexedDB object itself?

Comment: I hear ya jasondavis. The reason I'm working on the project is because of the complexity. I'm in rewrite three of an IndexedDB-based app. In the first round, I found myself writing the same low-level code over and over -- transactions, cursors, etc. So I created a thin but simplified API over the core stuff. Round two, I found myself writing the same convenience methods on top of that core stuff, so I made the low level plumbing private and exposed a new even more simplified API. The hope is that it can maintain the flavor oif IndexedDB without scaring away developers like yourself.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter version (based on names from [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)):

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.moz_indexedDB;
```